# Detect song by it's instrumental version

Tags: music-recognition

Is there something that can detect a song (with vocal) using only the instrumental version (i.e. without vocal) of this song?

I have a music that is the instrumental version of the original with vocal, but the name of this instrumental music is different from the original, so I can't know what is the name of that song.

So I'm asking if anyone know if exists any software (or website, maybe) that can do this kind of detection.

Comment: What operating system does it need to run on? Do you have a budget?

Comment: @Undo Well, it would be better if it could run on Windows and free, but currently I just want to know if there is a software able to do that.

Comment: If it's just one song, you could try a site like Reddit's r/tipofmytonge: https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/

Answer (score 2):

If you can match the instrumental version of the song to [MusicBrainz](http://musicbrainz.org) I expect there will be the required links to the vocal version of the song even if it does have a different name. In MusicBrainz you should have a relationship linking the two.

For example [here](https://musicbrainz.org/recording/eaae9754-a043-47ef-ae67-05d24f964aee) we have the instrumental version of Billie Jean by Michale Jackson, and as you can see if you click on the link there is a relationship called **instrumental recording of** which links it to the vocal version.

I'm not clear if when you say

> but the name of this instrumental music is different from the original

if you simply mean the name is different to the vocal version, or if the name is just completely unknown i.e *Track 1*

But if it is unknown you can use a Music tagger that can identify songs by *acoustic fingerprinting*.

For example **I am the developer** of the SongKong Music Tagger, and this can identify songs by acoustic fingerprints to MusicBrainz songs, you should then be able to look up the song on MusicBrainz to identify the vocal version. SongKong is available for Windows, OSX and Linux.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Shazam on iPhone or Android.

It will detect the song whether it's instrumental or not. Once you know the name of the song you can search google or youtube for it. If there is an instrumental version of a song it will usually show up on the first or second page of the search results. If it doesn't then do a new search but when you search enter the song name and add the word "instrumental" to the search criteria.